# How disabling FrontPage Server Extensions 2002 (IIS 6.0) will affect my web applications?

Tags: asp.net

in other words, what happens when I enable/disable FrontPage Server Extensions 2002 ?
knowing that I have asp.net web apps using .NET framework 1.1 and 2.0
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

FrontPage Server Extensions is an option that some (mostly older) HTML editors (FrontPage in particular) used for *deploying* web pages. It has no effect at all on an actually-running application.

You should probably turn it off, it's been a source of security vulnerabilities in the past, and there's better methods for deploying web applications anyway.